# Motor shaft adapter cannot be removed

Tags: motor, materials, mechanical-assembly

Motors that I have worked with in the past are as simple as can be, having
just one long cylindrical metal shaft sticking out from the magnetic
interior (and thereby allowing the "end product maker" to friction fit
anything to that main shaft).

But, today, I took a 24V DC brushed motor ("Johnson" brand) from a broken
hair dryer and found a little metal sleeve on the main shaft, as in the
photo below (not shown in the photo is the plastic fan blade which was
friction fit to the outside of this sleeve).  In the upper right,
to be clear, the outer sleeve and main shaft are aligned flush with each
other where they both terminate.

How is this sleeve attached to the shaft and how can I remove it?
I see no perpendicular screws keeping the sleeve on, so my first thought
was that this too is a friction fit, but I could not remove it with normal
prying.  So, maybe a metal-to-metal friction fit does not work well at
this small scale, and I now wonder if the two metal pieces were soldered
together...but that too seems unlikely.  So, how did "Johnson" get these
two metal pieces so tightly stuck together?

(By the way, I don't see any engineering use for this extra sleeve between
the main shaft and the plastic fan blade, and assume that this sleeve
just serves as an adapter to get the proper diameter and avoid redesigning
some given plastic fan blade.)

[image: motor]

Comment: Perhaps the copper sleeve is heated to expand first, before forcing it to marry with the steel shaft.

Comment: probably just pressed on

Comment: The "engineering" use is to match the smaller motor shaft to the fan blade - perhaps that is the cheapest blade in that format and if you ask for a different hole size the price goes up.

Comment: @SolarMike I agree.  That is what I tried to say  by "adapter to get the proper diameter".

Comment: do you want to keep the sleeve?

Comment: @Jasen No, I do not want to keep the sleeve.

Comment: use a nut splitter then. or a grinder etc. pincers even might work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not involve electronixs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So use a puller to remove the sleeve.

A flat bladed screwdriver is a poor substitute and even with a pry-bar on one side you could bend the shaft. Even if you used two opposing pry-bars you could still bend the shaft.

Comment: I did try to pry equally on opposing sides at the same time, but was not perfect of course. So, how do you think this sleeve was placed on originally to cause it to become so tight now? Maybe this is a trade secret...

Comment: You have been given the answer to that "trade secret" twice.

Comment: Yes, I guess, but that trade secret makes me think that no puller would get it off either, unless it's a heated puller.  I am tempted to cold pry it until I either break the shaft or succeed, but not yet that desperately curious.

Comment: @bobuhito have you ever used a puller? Have you any idea of the force it can apply? If not get one and see.

Comment: @bobuhito - Your last comment reveals that you really don't know how a gear puller works. Do some homework. It doesn't work the way you seem to think it does.